# Middleman, where can I add custom methods, which modify output of the views

Tags: ruby, sinatra, middleman

I am using middleman for building an API description web page, and I wonder if it is possible to define methods somewhere which will be used to parse YAML in desired format, basically I am looking for the place where I can put my helper methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put mine in the `config.rb` inside a `helpers` block, e.g.

```
helpers do
  def emphasise word
    word ?
      "<em>#{word}</em>" :
      word
  end

  def bracket word
    word ?
      "(#{word})" :
      word
  end
end
```

That helper will then be in scope for use in a template.

---

Edit: I found [the section of the docs for defining custom helpers](https://middlemanapp.com/basics/helper_methods/#custom-defined-helpers)

Comment: I have a partial, and I want to access the method from the helpers block, but I got the exception that method is missing, do I need to reference it somewhere or?

Comment: @IliaAptsiauri I didn't have to for mine, that should be enough. Are you able to share the error message? (and perhaps the helper and template, but at least the error)

Comment: That's the error I am getting. In config.rb file as you said I have the method  NoMethodError at /
undefined method `render_objects_prop' for #<Middleman::Application:0x70286487252660>

Comment: @IliaAptsiauri I found the link to the docs, it's in the answer now. Take a look and see if it gives you any insight. You've stopped and restarted the server?